# Which if any esperanto words are not viable as affixes for constructing new words?

Tags: affixes, word-formation

For example it seems to me that *la* probably isn't viable. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 9):

Any word is viable as part of a compound. The only limitation is whether it makes sense. Even "la" could be used in a compound if it makes sense to do so.

As a contrived example: *senlaa frazo*.

Comment: Could you please add a bit more on what *senlaa frazo* would mean? I'm having a hard time making any sense of it.

Comment: Oh sorry, "a sentence without a *la*". Clever! :-)

Answer (score -1):

*Je* can't be a prefix, *ĉe* is less common than other prepositions but it's used, like *ĉeesti* and other forms of that word. I don't see how *la* could be a prefix so you're probably right on that one.

Comment: Why can’t je be a prefix? There’s nothing in the grammar rules preventing a construction like ”Mi ĵuras je Zeŭso…” > ”Mi jeĵuras Zeŭson.” Also, when you’re in doubt about another prepositional prefix, ”je-” could come handy: ”prilabori/perlabori” > ”jelabori”. If it sounds strange, I think it’s just because people haven’t used it yet! :-)

Comment: I was just searching Tekstaro for counter examples and came up with that very same example: ŝi **jeĵuris** min en la nomo de mia amo al ŝi kaj al vi, ke mi ne forpuŝu la amon, kiun, kiel ŝi scias, vi transportos sur min, kiam la nun ankoraŭ freŝa vundo estos sanigita, sed ke mi ĝin vigligu kaj redonu

Comment: Neither PIV or PMEG had a section about je as a prefix and since some of the roles of je could be replaced by another preposition it didn't seem likely that you'd use it like that.

Comment: ”Ili tostis jehomare kaj plutrinkis.” = ”Ili tostis je la homaro kaj plutrinkis” :-) Never say never in the world of Esperanto!

Comment: eĉ zamenhofa ... [jeĵuri kontraŭ iu](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/jxur.html#jxur.je0ikun0i)